# problem issue in using checkbox in datatable

Tags: icefaces

I want to use  as a column in datateble and
I my code is

```
</ice:checkbox>

</ice:column>
```

but I got this error:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find UISelectMany component for checkbox."

can any body help me and tell me what is the right way to use checkbox in dataTable

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using something like

```
<ice:column>

    </ice:checkbox value="#{BEAN.ATTRIBUTE}"></ice:checkbox>

</ice:column>
```

Make sure to define BEAN in Faces-config.xml as managed bean and Attribute should be a member of that bean of type boolean.